# Change data-icon on click with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is my code:

```
function togglePOIAndDisplay(toggle){
    var display = $(toggle).attr('data-icon');
    console.log(display);
    if(display == 'minus'){
        $(toggle).attr('data-icon', 'check');
            console.log(display);
    } else {
        $(toggle).attr('data-icon', 'minus');
        removeMarkers(toggle);
    }
}
```

It will log `minus` to the console and go into the first if() block and executes displayAllPOIOfType() correctly, but it will not reflect the change of the value although it gets set correctly. Any ideas why that is, because it obviously reads/sets the attribute correctly.

Is there an update `function` I need to call? thanks

Comment: toggle is the selector to get the element. it works because it reads the attribute of "data-icon" correctly. so why wouldn't it work the second time?

Comment: Are you really sure the attribute isn't set ? Could you log it just after `$(toggle).attr('data-icon', 'check');` ?

Comment: it may be because your creating a new element on the fly. you might have to use delegate or on

Comment: @RPM That doesn't create an element, just a jQuery object (all share the same attributes if that's the same element).

Comment: @dystroy: just did that and it logs 'minus'.

Comment: Hey, you're logging `console.log(display)`, that's useless ! log `$(toggle).attr('data-icon')`.

Comment: you are right, it actually gets set, but just doesn't change. Seems I need to find an update function or somethiing.

Comment: Build a fiddle because the problem isn't in the code we see.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This depends on whether it's a button, or a select, or some other thing that accepts the `data-icon` attribute. Unfortunately, jQuery Mobile doesn't have great support for dynamically changing things controlled by `data-*` attributes, so you'll have to adjust the attribute as well as modify the classes on the child elements.

For buttons, something like this ought to work:

```
$(buttonSelector).attr('data-icon', newIcon);
                 .find('.ui-icon')
                     .addClass('ui-icon-' + newIcon)
                     .removeClass('ui-icon-' + oldIcon);
```

Comment: Thanks - useful. I wanted to toggle the data-split-icon in a collapsible and did this: $(this).find(".ui-icon").addClass("ui-icon-newicon").removeClass("ui-icon-oldicon"), where $(this) is the object containing the split button.

Comment: This does, in fact, change the data-icon value to the newIcon value... but the actual image used for the button doesn't change.  Thoughts?

Comment: This is a pretty old question, and I expect there's likely a later version of jQuery Mobile that does a better job than the one that this question is regarding (if memory serves, 1.0 or maybe 1.1?).

Answer (score 8):

If the icon is inside a button like this:

```
<a id="buttonID" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Button</a>
```

You can change the icon with the buttonMarkup function:

```
$('#buttonID').buttonMarkup({ icon: "check" });
```

Or to your custom icon:

```
$('#buttonID').buttonMarkup({ icon: "my-icon" });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u8fnJ/1/

As shown in this post [How to refresh a button in a header with jQueryMobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491879/how-to-refresh-a-button-in-a-header-with-jquerymobile#answer-9491988)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/8pwFK/29/

change custom icon to star icon.

```
$(this).attr('data-icon','star');
$(this).find('.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-custom').addClass('ui-icon-star');
```

this example is easy to study.

Comment: This is one year old and the solution has been posted, accepted and your answer is the exact copy of that.

Comment: @DatProgram yes, your question may be solved,but other people may have the same problem in the future, and yes, FMM give a good answer, but i just give a supplementary of it. and this may give convenience to others.

Comment: could have posted that link as a comment to his solution though, no need to write the same answer as a "new" answer.

Comment: @DatProgram through the original answer I spend 6-10 minutes, but the answer I added , others may need only 2-3 minutes to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

For listviews, you need to insert a span.

```
$("#times").off('click','li').on("click","li",function() {

 /* add a checkbox when you click the listview li  */
 $(this).find('div.ui-li').append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>');

});
```