# How to update the value of data attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap data toggle markup and I want to change the icon and the text to change on toggle. I can get the text to change but not the icon. What I'm I doing wrong?

```
 <div id="collapseDiv" >
    <dl>
      <dt>...</dt>
      <dd>...</dd>
    </dl> 
 </div>

 <a href="#collapseDiv" data-toggle="collapse" class="icon-before" data-icon="&#xf196">Show More</a>
```

Jquery code is as follows

```
 $('#collapseDiv').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('.icon-before').data('icon', '&#xf147').text('Show Less');
 });

$('#collapseDiv').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.icon-before').data('icon', '&#xf196').text('Show More');
});
```

Comment: I think you need to update `class` also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627864/change-data-icon-on-click-with-jquery-mobile see this

Comment: The `.data` method doesn't actually change attributes when storing data on an element (although it does read them for default values).  Try using `.attr('data-icon', '&#xf147')` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the attribute value, rather than updating data property:

```
$('#collapseDiv').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
 $('.icon-before').attr('data-icon', '&#xf147').text('Show Less');
});

$('#collapseDiv').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
 $('.icon-before').attr('data-icon', '&#xf196').text('Show More');
});
```

Comment: `data` also do the same thing

Comment: @Tushar No - `.data()` doesn't change attributes

Comment: @Tushar: It does not. data modifies the property and not attribute value,

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes it does `data('icon', 'newVal')` updates the value

Comment: It _does not change the attribute_, it uses some internal data storage mechanism.  It _does_ read the attribute for a default value, but it will never update it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `attr()`

```
attr('data-icon', '&#xf147')
```

Also check this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

**EXPLANATION**

Check the following example.

If you click on `span#one` the attribute changes with `attr()` function, if you click on `span#two` we will try to change the attribute with `data()` function.

When you try to select the element with `[data-test="false"]` only the first element has changes it's data attribute.

Only the element with `data-test="false"` will get red:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var id = that.attr('id');
  if (id == 'one') {
    //Try with attr()
    that.attr('data-test', 'false');
  } else if (id == 'two') {
    //Try with data()
    that.data('test', 'false');
  }
  $('[data-test="false"]').css({'color':'red'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="one" data-test="true">one</span>
<span id="two" data-test="true">two</span>
```

Comment: `data` does the same thing

Comment: No, data just stores arbitary data to a specific element

Comment: data does not change attribute

Comment: And if you use `attr('data-test', newval)` and not `data('test', newval)` then if you later use `data('test')` it will give the **old** value.  So it entirely depends on how you're using it later.

Answer (score 0):

You should also update class of .ui-icon inside.

```
var oldIcon = $('.icon-before').data('icon'),
    newIcon = '&#xf147';
    uiIcon = $('.icon-before').data('icon', newIcon).find('.ui-icon');
uiIcon.removeClass('ui-icon-' + oldIcon).addClass('ui-icon-' + newIcon);
```