# Iconify icon not updating when "data-icon" set with setAttribute()

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to animate/replace an icon but "setAttribute" method doesn't seem to work.. what's wrong with my code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.3/iconify.min.js"></script>

<body>
<a href="#" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-grey w3-hide-small w3-right">
<i id="t1" class="iconify" data-icon="ic:round-wifi"></i></a>
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="wifiOff()">OFF</button>
<script>
function wifiOff(){
  var x = document.getElementById("t1");
  if (x.hasAttribute("data-icon")) {
    x.setAttribute("data-icon", "ic:round-wifi-off");
    console.log(x);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works. I've updated your snippet. Press the button and x with its new attribute will be logged.

Comment: Hey, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627864/change-data-icon-on-click-with-jquery-mobile

Comment: The attribute is being set, but iconify is not updating the display

Comment: you should add an iconify tag as the issue is probably there

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729088/iconify-not-reacting-to-changes-in-dom

Comment: I believe you need to have both icons available and switch between the two.  You can show and hide the different icons on click.  (or create/destroy the <i> elements on click.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, iconify updates icon when u replace the full element.

So why not just use to hide and unhide icons on button click?

I believe the example below works for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.3/iconify.min.js"></script>
<style>.hidden{display:none;}</style>
<body>
<a href="#" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-grey w3-hide-small w3-right">
<i id="t1" class="iconify" data-icon="ic:round-wifi"></i><i id="t2" class="iconify hidden" data-icon="ic:round-wifi-off"></i></a>
<br>
<br>

<button onclick="wifiToggle()">OFF</button>
<script>
function wifiToggle(){
  var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
  var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
      t1.classList.toggle("hidden");
      t2.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not appear to be supported by Iconify.

If you look at Iconify's source, you'll see that [it uses](https://github.com/iconify/iconify/blob/c72f8b7862dfb633627b0e1cceb2b279248cb957/src/browser/with-observer/observer.js#L136) the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to get notified when the DOM changes.  While that API does allow for observing DOM attributes by specifying `attributes: true` in the observer configuration, [Iconify does not have this enabled](https://github.com/iconify/iconify/blob/c72f8b7862dfb633627b0e1cceb2b279248cb957/src/browser/with-observer/observer.js#L33-L36).  Thus, it's not getting notified and not updating the icon.